# How to add the Share function to Android app with Corona SDK?

Tags: android, share, android-contentprovider, coronasdk

I'd like to add an image sharing function to the Corona SDK app on Android. But I don't want the email/twitter/fb sharing I can write my own code for. What I'd like instead is to use the native "share" function that enables all sharing providers to be selected.

So a popup for this would look like this:

[image]

How can this be done in Corona SDK? (and is it possible at all? Not with Corona Enterprise?)

Comment: You can vote for this feature to be implemented here: http://feedback.coronalabs.com/forums/188732-corona-sdk-feature-requests-feedback/suggestions/3575020-android-share-image-and-text-intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corona SDK has a plugin for this.  See:

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2013/10/11/revisiting-the-social-plugin-now-on-android/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with Corona Enterprise, but I don't know how (I don't own Corona Enterprise).

Otherwise, no, it cannot be done.

EDIT for december of 2013:

It now can be done using a plug-in

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2013/10/11/revisiting-the-social-plugin-now-on-android/

Comment: It can be done: http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2013/10/11/revisiting-the-social-plugin-now-on-android/